# On-purpose int overflow

Tags: go, type-conversion, integer-overflow

I'm using the hash function `murmur2` which returns me an `uint64`.

I want then to store it in PostgreSQL, which only support `BIGINT` (signed 64 bits).

As I'm not interested in the number itself, but just the binary value (as I use it as an id for detecting uniqueness (my set of values being of ~1000 values, a 64bit hash is enough for me) I would like to convert it into `int64` by "just" changing the type.

How does one do that in a way that pleases the compiler?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can simply use a type [conversion](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Conversions):

```
i := uint64(0xffffffffffffffff)
i2 := int64(i)
fmt.Println(i, i2)
```

Output:

```
18446744073709551615 -1
```

Converting `uint64` to `int64` always succeeds: it doesn't change the memory representation just the type. What may confuse you is if you try to convert an untyped integer constant value to `int64`:

```
i3 := int64(0xffffffffffffffff) // Compile time error!
```

This is a compile time error as the constant value `0xffffffffffffffff` (which is represented with arbitrary precision) does not fit into `int64` because the max value that fits into `int64` is `0x7fffffffffffffff`:

```
constant 18446744073709551615 overflows int64
```

Comment: ok, yes I was under a false impression on how type conversion was working, thanks for clarifying things