# Proper way for casting uint16 to int16 in Go

Tags: go, bit-manipulation, uint16

Bitwise manipulation and Go newbie here :D I am reading some data from sensor with Go and I get it as 2 bytes - let's say `0xFFFE`. It is easy too cast it to uint16 since in Go we can just do `uint16(0xFFFE)` but what I need is to convert it to integer, because the sensor returns in fact values in range from -32768 to 32767. Now I thought *"Maybe Go will be this nice and if I do `int16(0xFFFE)` it will understand what I want?"*, but no. I ended up using following solution (I translated some python code from web):

```
x := 0xFFFE

if (x & (1 << 15)) != 0 {
    x = x - (1<<16)
}
```

It seems to work, but A) I am not entirely sure why, and B) It looks a bit ugly to what I imagined should be a trivial solution for casting uint16 to int16. Could anyone give me a hand and clarify why this is only way to do this? Or is there any other possible way?

Comment: A minor nitpick: Go does not have type casting; it rather has type conversions.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

But what you want works, "Go is nice":

```
ui := uint16(0xFFFE)
fmt.Println(ui)
i := int16(ui)
fmt.Println(i)
```

Output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/z1vFjFRUVii)):

```
65534
-2
```

`int16(0xFFFE)` doesn't work because `0xfffe` is an untyped integer constant which cannot be represented by a value of type `int16`, that's why the the compiler complains. But you can certainly convert any `uint16` non-constant value to `int16`.

See possible duplicates:

[Golang: on-purpose int overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34704843/golang-on-purpose-int-overflow/34704898#34704898)

[Does go compiler's evaluation differ for constant expression and other expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39444852/does-go-compilers-evaluation-differ-for-constant-expression-and-other-expressio/39445372#39445372)

Comment: I have tried it in a bit different form `fmt.Println(int16(uint16(0xFFFE)))` and it throws overflow error. Why does it work in your example then?

Comment: @Devlige Because constant values can only be converted if the type can represent the exact value. In my example I am not converting a constant but a variable, where overflow is allowed (just like in any other language). For an explanation in great details, please check: [Does go compiler's evaluation differ for constant expression and other expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39444852/does-go-compilers-evaluation-differ-for-constant-expression-and-other-expressio/39445372#39445372)

Comment: Perfect! In conclusion Go is nice indeed. It just requires a bit more knowledge :) Thank you

Comment: @kostix Just when I wanted to post the link. That link contains the "more knowledge" regarding constants.

Comment: Seems this is only possible with vars, if writte as one-liner it fails: constant 65534 overflows int16